# Create new loop for duplicate index with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, duplicates

Quick question. I need to create an array using duplicated index. For example, I have an array like:

```
var array = [2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7];
```

And I need to get a new loop interaction for each duplicate index, the response should be something like:

```
[ 
  [2, 3, 4, 6, 7],
  [2, 3],
  [2],
]
```

Please let me know if is possible and how to create some function to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the logic behind the wanted results?

Comment: @Teemu: As I understand it, it looks like any time you encounter a value, you try putting it into the lowest-indexed output array that doesn't already have that number in it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to count how many of each number there are in the array?

Comment: Only if the count of each number is the desired output.

Comment: @Teemu, I need to call an API for each interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use one object to store number of occurrences for each element and use that value to create result array.

```js
var array = [2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7];
var obj = {}, result = []
array.forEach(function(e) {
  obj[e] == undefined ? obj[e] = 0 : obj[e] += 1;
  result[obj[e]] = (result[obj[e]] || []).concat(e)
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this

```js
var array = [2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7];
array.sort();
let idx = 0, result = [];
for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if(i>0 && array[i] != array[i-1]){
        idx = 0;
    }
    if(idx == result.length)
        result[idx] = [];
    result[idx].push(array[i]);
    idx++;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works fine and as expected! Thank you!